# how to connect to QBluetoothServer

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth

I have a code to listen for bluetooth connections

```
rfcommServer = new QBluetoothServer(QBluetoothServiceInfo::RfcommProtocol, this);
    connect(rfcommServer, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(clientConnected()));
    bool result = rfcommServer->listen(localAdapter);
```

how to code the client side of this so thaat clientConnected slot is called?
I found this code

```
    QBluetoothSocket * socket;
    socket = new QBluetoothSocket(QBluetoothServiceInfo::RfcommProtocol);
            qDebug() << "Create socket";
            socket->connectToService(remoteService);
qDebug() << "ConnectToService done";
```

where remoteService is declared as `QBluetoothServiceInfo &remoteService;`

but how do I initialize remoteService?

And can I use `rfcommServer->listen(localAdapter);` in both client side and server side, because, I want to use both side as server, that is both sides can accept incoming connections.

Comment: Isn't it just sending the signal expected by the slot from the client side?

Comment: no it is not, one more thing it was written to add import QtBluetooth 5.2 to qml file, but I have not added. There is no qml file.

Comment: Have you checked this example? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-btchat-example.html

Comment: yes, I have copied my code from there

Comment: I have 2 laptops communicating, do I use rfcommServer->listen(localAdapter); in both the sides?

Comment: On the botton of the page, you have the whole project (section *files*). You can download it and check what is actually missing on your code...

Comment: I have checked from the bottom also, but it does not mention how to connect to this chat application.

Comment: here also there is no qml file

Comment: The code over there is complete and runnable... You could download all files, build the project and run line by line with QTCreator's debugger. I'm not an expert on QT, but you don't actually need any qml file to build an UI, neither need it to connect signals and slots...